# Square of Normal distributed variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

This is a quick question. If $X\sim\operatorname{Normal}$, is $X^2$ rayleigh distributed?
I ask this question is because from wiki, it says $X^2$ is called the Chi-Squared Distribution with a degree freedom of $1$.

How does that reduce to the rayleigh distribution?

---

Update:

According to wiki:

> A second example of the distribution arises in the case of random
>   complex numbers whose real and imaginary components are i.i.d.
>   (independently and identically distributed) Gaussian with equal
>   variance and zero mean. In that case, the absolute value of the
>   complex number is Rayleigh-distributed.

Comment: Why the lack of reaction to the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the real and imaginary parts are gaussian distributed with zero mean and same variance, $A^2+B^2$ follows chi-square distribution. Absolute value of a complex number is given by $\sqrt{(A^2+B^2)}$, which is a square root of chi-square r.v, hence follows chi distribution with two dof. According to wiki, Rayleigh distribution is essentially chi distribution with two degrees of freedom. But if $X$ is a normal r.v, $X^2$ follows chi-square distribution with one dof, not rayleigh distribution.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Rayleigh distribution involves multiplying by $x$ in the definition for the density at $x$, so $X^2$ is not Rayleigh distributed and in general Chi-squared and Rayleigh distributions are always different. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution#Related_distributions for various non-linear relationships that do hold between Rayleigh and other distributions, including Chi-squared.